# Is it possible to speed up devectorized Julia codes

Tags: performance, julia

As a part of my script. I have some codes which are as follows (devectorized julia -as possible as)

```
for kk=1:n # Main loop
    for j=1:m
        rhs[j]=2*u0[j]-alf*dt*u1[j]-2*mu*u2[j];    
    end
    c=lhs\rhs'; #c: coefficients to be obtained

    u2=c'*h;
    u1=c'*p.-c'*f;
    u0=c'*Q-c'*f*x;

    for j=1:m
        for i=1:m
            lhs[j,i]=2*(Q[i,j]-x[j]*f[i])+alf*dt*(p[i,j]-f[i])+eps*dt*(Q[i,j]-x[j]*f[i])*u1[j]+eps*u0[j]*dt*(p[i,j]-f[i])-2*mu*h[i,j];
        end
    end

end
```

where h, p, Q, lhs are `mxm` matrices; u0, u1, u2, rhs and x are `1xm` arrays, alf, dt, mu, eps are scalar constants and f, c are `mx1` arrays. I  preallocated the matrices and arrays at the start of the script. Vectorized form of the above codes are as follows

```
for kk=1:n # Main loop

    rhs=2*u0-alf*dt*u1-2*mu*u2;    

    c=lhs\rhs'; #c coefficients to be obtained

    u2=c'*h;
    u1=c'*p.-c'*f;
    u0=c'*Q-c'*f*x;

    lhs=2*(Q-f*x)+alf*dt*(p.-f)+eps*dt*(Q-f*x).*u1+eps*dt*u0.*(p.-f)-2*mu*h;
    lhs=lhs';

end
```

For example for n=100 and m=64 the elapsed times are as follows:

devectorized julia: 1.8 seconds

vectorized julia: 0.2 seconds

vectorized numpy: 0.04 seconds

the vectorized julia code is approximately 9 times faster than devectorized julia code and vectorized python code is approximately 5 times faster than the vectorized julia code.

For n=500 and m=256

devectorized julia: 85.589233013 seconds

vectorized julia: 8.232898003 seconds

vectorized numpy: 1.62000012398 seconds

My question: Is it possible to increase the performance of julia in this case?

Comment: you should check out the [performance tips](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/) section of the documentation. Specifically, look at the parts for [accessing arrays according to memory order](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/#access-arrays-in-memory-order-along-columns) and running all code inside functions instead of at the top level.

Comment: you seem to be running in global scope, which is why vectorized versions are faster since they get out of global scope faster

Comment: @spencerlyon2: Putting all the codes into functions  increase the performance very well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

i think it's possible to also devectorize calculation of `u0,u1,u2` like this:

```
function vectorized()
    m = [1.0 2.0 3.0; 1.0 2.0 3.0; 1.0 2.0 3.0]
    c = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]

    for i in 1:100000
        x1 = c'*m
        x2 = c'*m
        x3 = c'*m
    end

    return
end

function vectime(N)
    timings = Array(Float64, N)

    # Force compilation
    vectorized()

    for itr in 1:N
        timings[itr] = @elapsed vectorized()
    end

    return timings
end

println("vectorized=",mean(vectime(20)))

function devectorized()
    m = [1.0 2.0 3.0; 1.0 2.0 3.0; 1.0 2.0 3.0]
    c = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
    x1 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    x2 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    x3 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    mx = 3
    for i in 1:100000
        for k in 1:mx
            for kk in 1:mx
              x1[k]=x1[k]+c[k]*m[k,kk];
              x2[k]=x2[k]+c[k]*m[k,kk];
              x3[k]=x3[k]+c[k]*m[k,kk];
            end
        end
    end
    return
end

function dvectime(N)
    timings = Array(Float64, N)

    # Force compilation
    devectorized()

    for itr in 1:N
        timings[itr] = @elapsed devectorized()
    end

    return timings
end

println("devectorized=",mean(dvectime(20)))
```

above code results:

```
vectorized=0.17680755404999998
devectorized=0.00441064295
```